# which DBMS should i go for?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, oracle, rdbms

I am interested in learning a DBMS. As a beginner which DBMS should i go for ?

I know few DBMS by name like Oracle,Sql Server,My Sql  .  *How are these DBMS different from each other ?*

*As a beginner which DBMS should i go for ?* I needed to learn DBMS as i am working with JavaEE and had to link the project with a database.

Comment: How are these DBMS different from each other? Very broad question. Understanding your requirements beyond JavaEE would help determine which DBMS would be appropriate. Are you interested in learning how to become an ETL developer, application developer who understands SQL, or become a database administrator?

Comment: What are the requirements for the application, it's database and the environment? SQL Server runs pretty bad on a Linux machine...

Comment: @ RobPaller application developer who understands a DBMS. I want to introduce myself to a DBMS

Comment: @ Frank Heikens Windows.

Comment: @ RobPaller Even in general which DBMS should i go for when i don't know any ?

Comment: Sorry Suhail, this just isn't the right place to ask this question - see the [faq](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#questions): "but this is *not* the right place to ask questions about... what platform you should learn next, including which technology is better in general terms"

Answer (score 4):

> Since you want to be application developer who understands a DBMS.

In my opinion there exists, five foremost databases in minds of developers. These are

- Oracle
- DB2
- SQL Server
- My SQL
- PostgreSQL

Why these five, first three because of market share. Last two because of usage share in open source applications.

> Also you stated that you are working with JavaEE.

Then I suggest you choose one of the following. In the following order.

1. PostgreSQL Open Source
2. DB2 (Universal) Express Edition
3. Oracle Express Edition
4. MySQL
5. SQL Server Express Edition

I put SQL Server last since you are working with Java. Other databases are more appropriate. Note that I am Certified in SQL Server (2000,2005,2008). Therefore this is not a bias in my opinion but I acknowledge that others are more strong with Java.

I put MySQL in last rows since I believe you should start with a DBMS which supports SQL Standard more, and first three are better (out of box) than MySQL in this regard.

There are not much difference for **learning application development** with first three. If you are to be primarily open source developer choose PostgreSQL. If you are to be primarily commercial developer, look your local career site. Which DBMS wanted more, choose it. For example Oracle is more popular in my local area.

Comment: PostgreSQL is also a great database for closed source software, it has a license (BSD/MIT style) without restrictions like GPL.